# Share text with WhatsApp on Android "Can't send empty message"

Tags: android, whatsapp

When I'm trying to share text using intent mechanism and pick WhatsApp, it says:

> Can't send empty message

I've read an official docs about Android integration here: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000012

My code:

```
public void shareText(String label, CharSequence title, CharSequence body) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title.toString());
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, TextUtils.concat(title, body));

        final Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, label);
        chooser.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        if (chooser.resolveActivity(mContext.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            mContext.startActivity(chooser);
        }
 }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it bug with WhatsApp messenger?

P.S. arguments `title` and `body` are not empty in my case.

Comment: Do you want a send empty message?

Comment: No, actually title and body are not empty.

Comment: Have you checked if it's empty?

Comment: @sanjeev lot of times, even added assert statement. 
Also it is working with Telegram and Gmail, Evernote, but not with WhatsApp

Comment: Have you tried it by removing `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title.toString());` and sharing in whatsapp? Sometimes the apps may not support subject?

Comment: @sanjeev When I put constant String to Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, it is working with Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT as in my example. But not vice versa

Comment: @sanjeev it seems the issue is in this line: intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, TextUtils.concat(title, body));
Because when I change it by intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Constant text"); it is working. Maybe whatsApp do not support spanned text?

Comment: @OleksandrAlbul check my answer and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you have done is,

`intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, TextUtils.concat(title, body));`

while `TextUtils.concat(title, body)` returns `CharSequence` probably that whatsapp does not support.

You have to pass the value as a String leaving you two solutions.

- **You can convert the whole to a String by toString()**

`intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, TextUtils.concat(title, body).toString());`

- **Converting it a String before passing it to intent.**

`String someValue = TextUtils.concat(title, body).toString();`

and adding it here as,

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, someValue);
```

Comment: you are correct. But it is frustrating experience, as other messengers and apps could accept CharSequence and strip formatting if it is not supported.
So I will set plain String to Intent.EXTRA_TEXT and also add html presentation of Spannable like this:
`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT, Html.toHtml(TextUtils.concat(title, body)));
}`

Comment: Yeah that seems like a pretty good way to approach and makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here You can send data from your app to `Whatsapp` and any other like a `messenger`

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("text/plain");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,   " Your text ");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,  " Your text "));
```

Comment: This is like copy-paste from official docs. Have tried this exact example and it is working. But what is wrong with my case? I do not need to send " Your text " litteral

Answer (score 0):

Here sendEmtpyMassages is Button Just copy this method It's Work for you

```
sendEmtpyMassages.setOnClickListener {
        val context: Context = applicationContext
        val sendIntent = Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN")
        sendIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
        sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp")
        val url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + "&text=" + " "
        sendIntent.data = Uri.parse(url)
        if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(context.packageManager) != null) {
            startActivity(sendIntent)
        }
    }
```